# Compatibility mode Nexus 4 & Nexus 7

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I though I had finally understood how compatibility mode worked, but just tested a new application and can't get assets resolutions work as I expected.

I have drawables for `hdpi` and `xdpi` densities, and everything's rendered fine on *Nexus 4*, but when I deploy in *Nexus 7*, the size of the assets rendered is pretty much smaller than it should.

As far as I know, enabling compatibility mode for large/xlarge screens should let you see an application *autoscaled* in the same way iPad scales up iPhone apps, but after reading android all documentation about [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [screen compatibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) several times, I get the 'correct resolution' in one of the devices, not both.-

My `AndroidManifest.xml` contains.-

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:largeScreens="false" android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

With this configuration, the app looks perfect in Nexus 4, but not in tablet. However, if I change `resizeable` to `false`, it correctly scales the assets on tablet, but mobile shows too large assets.

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious here, or adjusting resolutions and compatibility mode configurations is really that hard. Could anyone give me some tip?

Comment: Which Nexus 7? the new one? old one? Anyway is a large device, why you're setting android:largeScreens="false"?

Comment: Old one. `largeScreens` was just a blind shot when I lost sanity :)

Comment: afaik Nexus 7 (old) is a large-tvdpi device. xhdpi resources will be scaled down in a tvdpi device.

Comment: Mmh so the only solution would be copy-paste my hdpi resources in tvdpi? :(

Comment: For tablets (large and xlarge) check here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

Comment: Thanks, been there, but I don't want to create specific assets for tablet, I'm trying to activate compatibility mode so that android scales the appropriate ones.

Comment: You don't have to activate the compatibility mode. Layout and resources will be up/down scaled automatically based on which resources you provide and for which configuration.